# Recursive Name Search

Tags: java, search, recursion

i want to find a name in a recursivly build itemlist.
Items can have subitems which can have subsubitems etc.

For the first level it worked. for deeper levels the correctly found name/id mapping gets an overwrite from the stack. Because of the string result, i have to write the return statement at the end. So i have a mental blockage how i can solve this problem. I appreciate for your help.

```
public String getNameForID(List<Item> top, long id, String name ) {

        for (Item i : top) {
            if (i.getId() == id) {
                name =  i.getName();
                return name;
            }else{
             this.getNameForID(i.getSubItemsList(), id,name);
            }

        }
        return name;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must be what you're looking for:

```java
public String getNameById(List<Item> items, long id) {
    // boundary condition
    if (items == null || items.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    // looping
    for (Item item : items) {
        // if current is
        if (item.getId() == id) {
            return item.getName();
        }
        // recursion
        String name = getNameById(item.getSubItemsList(), id);
        // if nested found
        if (name != null) {
            return name;
        }
    }
    // boundary condition
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your recursive call to `getNameForID` **must** also be able to return a value.  It also needs to be able to indicate that *no value was found* so that the recursion is terminated.

Based on @sp00m's previously deleted (and slightly incorrect) answer, try this:

```
public String getNameById(List<Item> items, long id) {

    // sanity checking conditions to terminate recursion early
    if (items == null || items.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }

    // iterate over collection
    for (Item item: items) {
        if (item.getId() == id) {
            return item.getName();
        } else {
            String name = getNameById(item.getSubItemsList(), id);
            if (name != null) {
                return name;
            }
        }
    }

    // final termination condition - entry wasn't in this list
    return null;
}
```

Comment: @sp00m so you did - I spotted the error in your original and posted a corrected version here.  Undelete yours and I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

you do not assign the value returned here to **name**:

```
this.getNameForID(i.getSubItemsList(), id,name);
```

actually you don't need the parameter name - just return **name** or **null** in each call